# Vagrant - Symfony box not found

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I'm getting this error when trying to use the Symfony Vagrant box:

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'elao/symfony-standard-debian;' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box  Version: >= 0
The box 'elao/symfony-standard-debian;' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/elao/symfony-standard-debian;"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

This is using the Vagrant environment here https://atlas.hashicorp.com/elao/boxes/symfony-standard-debian

Seems odd that a box with 14K downloads is giving a 404. Is that really the case or am I doing something wrong?

The commands I'm using are:

```
vagrant init elao/symfony-standard-debian;
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon. Commands to be used:

```sh
vagrant init elao/symfony-standard-debian
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```